# Испортился layout

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено

Испортился layout:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Аналогичный вопрос на MSE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343217/whats-the-skinny-on-the-user-profile-page)

Comment: У меня нормально. Какой браузер?

Comment: @Qwertiy Chrome, Mac OS X.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кстати сегодня уже вроде починили. Давайте повесим ему [meta-tag:статус-завершено].